# Is it possible to access a running instance of an app using JNA/JNI?

Tags: java, testing, java-native-interface, jna

I'm writing a test engine for a Java application that has some of the code written in C. This application uses JNI to access it's native part.

In the engine I'm writing, I use Fest to control de UI and perform the tests. However, I,m blind when dealing with the part that is written in C. I wonder if I can use JNA or JNI to access the native part of the app. I believe that the fact that the application is already running is huge issue here.

Comment: How exactly you want to 'access' it? (regardless of language, java or c) You want somethink like java reflection API for C?

Comment: The part that is written is C has a function that returns some XML in a string format. 
I'd like to make a call to this function and get this string in my test engine. I think yes, it's kind of in a reflection manner.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what the app does and what you want to do ?

Comment: The app is a graph app. It has some functions that are done with Java, and also some others that are implemented in C. The Java part of the app access the C part through JNI. I'd like to access the C part too, but from my testing engine. I can access the Java part using Fest in my engine. However, I cannot find a way to access the C part of it.

Comment: How about simply treating the C code as a black box, for a given input verify that the output is correct. That will not give you full coverage, but if you include boundary conditions you should be able to formulate a good set of tests. Just create all your tests in Java and forget about the C part.

Comment: That's how we're handling it. However, We got stuck in some points that this C code displays some dialogs that we should get rid of.

Answer (score 0):

You can access to a running java application with [Monitoring and Management
for the Java Platform](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/index.html) (and tools like [jvisualvm](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) and [jconsole](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jconsole.html)), and with [JavaTM Platform Debugger Architecture (JPDA)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/index.html)

All that is a little complicated... The most useful is the first.